# Implementing equals(), hashCode(), toString() in the hierarchy like the Optional<?> from Guava

Tags: java

I have simple hierarchy which looks [a little bit] like the `Optional<?>` from *Guava*:

```
public abstract class Result<T> {

    public static <ResultType> Result<ResultType> get(ResultType result) {
        return new PresentResult(result);
    }

    public static Result<?> absent(Throwable exception) {
        return new AbsentResult(exception);
    }

    Result() {
        // clients of the package can't extend this class
    }

    public abstract boolean isPresent();
    public abstract T get();
    public abstract Throwable getException();
}


class PresentResult<T> extends Result<T> {

    private final T result;

    public PresentResult(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPresent() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public T get() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getException() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof PresentResult)) {
            return false;
        }
        PresentResult<?> other = (PresentResult<?>) obj;
        return Objects.equal(get(), other.get());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(get());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("result", get())
                .toString();
    }
}


class AbsentResult extends Result {

    private final Throwable exception;

    public AbsentResult(Throwable exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPresent() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable getException() {
        return exception;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof AbsentResult)) {
            return false;
        }
        AbsentResult other = (AbsentResult) obj;
        return Objects.equal(getException(), other.getException());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getException());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("exception", getException())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure whether I implemented the methods `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()` correctly.

What do you think about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel your logic should mostly be pushed to the `Result` base class. Additionally, I feel it should have a generic type of `<... extends Throwable>` return value. I don't like the raw `Throwable` return at all...

Additionally, `isPresent` is a poor name, I would go for a name like `isException` which makes it more clear that there was a problem, rather than a potentially null value which is null, but still present.

You have some static generic methods that have unconventional generic typing...

> ```
> public static <ResultType> Result<ResultType> get(ResultType result) { .....
> ```

The above declares the genericType of `ResultType`. It is conventional in Java to use a single upper-case letter to declare generic types. I would have:

```
public static <R> Result<R> get(R result) {
```

Using the full `ResultType` implies there is a class called `ResultType`, which there is not.

The subclass hierarchy is also overkill. I would prefer a single final and immutable class. There is no reason why a single `hashCode` and `equals` cannot accommodate both sides of the result (with, and without an exception):

```
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Result<V, T extends Throwable> {

    public static <R, E extends Throwable> Result<R, E> get(R result) {
        return new Result<>(result, null);
    }

    public static <R, E extends Throwable> Result<R, E> absent(E xception) {
        if (xception == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot have an absent constructor with a null exception");
        }
        return new Result<>(null, xception);
    }

    private final V result;
    private final T xception;

    private Result(V result, T xception) {
        this.result = result;
        this.xception = xception;
    }

    public boolean isException() {
        return xception != null;
    }

    public V get() {
        if (xception != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot call get() for an exception Result.", xception);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public T getException() {
        if (xception == null) {
            // include cause throwable too.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot retrieve an exception when one was not set.");
        }
        return xception;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(xception) ^ Objects.hashCode(result);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object them) {
        if (this == them) {
             return true;
        }
        if (Result.class.isInstance(them)) {
            return Objects.equals(result, ((Result<?,?>)them).result) && Objects.equals(xception, ((Result<?,?>)them).xception); 
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Note that I suggest using [the `Objects` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-). The Objects class simplifies `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. I do a bitwise XOR on the hashcodes of the two values, but at most one will be set.

Note how this class would be used (a RuntimeException declaration will not need a throws clause, or a catch block).:

```
Result<Integer, RuntimeException> result = Result.get(55);

if (result.isException()) {
    throw result.getException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some remarks:

- Why does `getException()` return a `Throwable` instead of an `Exception`? Or even better, a `RuntimeException`? More generally, what is the purpose of this method? If I were you I'd "drop" it and make `.get()` throw the wanted exception instead. Since the exception would be a `RuntimeException`, there would be no need to declare it.
- Is it on purpose that `PresentResult` and `AbsentResult` are not `final`? What do you expect further subclasses to extend if anything?
- Is it legal to initialize a `PresentResult` with a null value, an `AbsentResult` with a null exception?

Comment: Sometimes, you should do some work in another thread and return result to "parent" thread (for example, `AsyncTask` in *android*). But it's possible that there is an exception occurs in that thread. This class can be useful in this case. Next. `PresentResult` and `AbsentResult` is not visible outside of the package contains them, so you can not subclass them.  As for the last remark, I think I shouldn't bound users to return only not-`null` value\exception. To check whether a result is present (i.e. `PresentResult`) or not, they can use the `isPresent()` method.